# gravatar.com takes most of the bandwidth while loading Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, support, gravatar, page-load

Why is gravatar.com taking most of the bandwidth while I load Stack Exchange? Is there a way to get rid of that, so I can load only Stack Exchange and not gravatar.com?

Comment: That is really a question for gravatar.com - SE is not to blame that it sucks big time these days (e.g. for me Gravatar pictures are not showing unless I browse directly to  the picture). They can, in theory, stop using it, but then people will complain even more.

Comment: tecnically, in an odd way, this is asking for a workaround to load Stack Exchange without having to load resources hosted at gravatar... which is somehow on topic even if it is just a case of the wider "how to load site X while blocking content from site Y". Leaving open *for now*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most images from Stack Exchange are cached, so you don't have to download them each time you visit a different page. Avatars (which are served from gravatar.com), however, are usually different on each page, because usually different questions and answers are posted by different people. For example, if you visit 100 random questions, you'll have to download hundreds of avatars, but other images (for example the logo of the site) will be downloaded only once.

Answer (score 0):

Most ad-blockers offer an option to block all traffic from a certain domain, for example gravatar.com. See for example [here](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters) if you're using Adblock Plus.

*Why* it is taking so long depends on a lot of factors, and not everybody (including me right now) will experience this.

Comment: Could also [add it to your hosts file](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=block+sites+with+hosts+file&ia=web) for a simple KISS solution. This should work for all major platforms.

Comment: Yeah, that would work as well.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker that will also apply to all users and all sites, and you will never figure out why some random page is glitched or why and when you added a specific line there. An ad blocker is a more manageable solution.